# If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both differentiable and $f(x)g(x) = 1$ for ALL $x$, show $\left[\frac{f’(x)}{f(x)} + \frac{g’(x)}{g(x)}\right] = 0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am able to conjure up a simple example such as $f(x) = x$, and $g(x) = \frac1x$, which will compute to $0$, but I am asking for help to write a more rigorous proof, not more rigorous examples, but fluency that that says why it works. Perhaps share any vital Theorems that would apply and how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$fg=1$ hence $f'g+fg'=(fg)'=0$ so $(f'g+fg')/(fg)=0$ thus $f'/f+g'/g=0$.

Comment: all of these examples are excellent, and I particularly like the simplicity of your effort. Is there a particular theorem or law that I should go study that helps state this as a rigorous proof? Or does this suffice for analysis? Is this merely the product rule?

Comment: Just the analysis!

Comment: I believe that is all the question asks, now that I stop over thinking it....thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

$h(x)=\log(f(x))+\log(g(x))=\log(f(x)g(x))=\log(1)=0$. It's differentiable due to differentiability of $f(x),g(x)$. Differentiate it on both sides, you will get the result.

Answer (score 2):

Consider function $h(x)=\ln(f(x)g(x))$. It's a constant function, so $h'(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. But on the other hand if you calculate derivative you get:

$$h'(x)=(\ln(f(x)g(x)))'=(\ln(f(x))+\ln(g(x)))'=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}+\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)}.$$

Answer (score 2):

If $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are both differentiable and $f(x)g(x) = 1$, then we have  $0 = 1' = (f(x)g(x))' = f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$, showing that $f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x) = 0$.  $f(x)g(x) = 1$ implies $f(x) \ne 0 \ne g(x)$, so we meaningfully have $g(x) = (f(x))^{-1}$ and $f(x) = (g(x))^{-1}$.  Inserting these into $f'(x)g(x) + f(x)g'(x)$ yields the desired result $f'(x)(f(x))^{-1} + g'(x)(g(x))^{-1} = 0$.

Nothing fancy.  It's merely the product rule (mostly).

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as ever,

***Fiat Lux!!!***,

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, the (non-linear) differential operator $f\mapsto \frac{f'}{f}$ ( the logarithmic derivative) takes products to sums. It's the differential analogue of:

$a \%$ increase followed by $b \% $ increase is (approximately) $(a+b)\%$ increase.